# How to make my Cocod2d game universal?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I just finished my new game using Cocos2d (v 0.99.1) for iPhone. Before releasing it on the AppStore, I would like to make my app universal so it can run fullscreen on iPad.
What are the changes I need to do to my App?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the answer: click “Project\Upgrade Current Target for iPad”.